# Track load progress for custom loading bar via beforeunload

Tags: javascript, onload, progress, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to use [nprogress](https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress) with a PWA I've built to show a loading bar, particularly when the app is launched in standalone mode.

My thought is to start the bar when `beforeunload` fires, and finish it just before the page actually unloads.

To do this, I've set up the following:

```
import NProgress from "nprogress";

window.onbeforeunload = () => {
    NProgress.start();
};

window.onunload = () => {
    NProgress.done();
};
```

Of course, I then came to find that `onunload` fires after the contents of the page becomes hidden, and thus my progress bar never gets a chance to finish.

I've tried changing so that when the next page loads the progress bar continues, but that doesn't work quite right either.

In the case of using `window.onload = () => { NProgress.done(); }`, the progress bar restarts from 0, rather than retaining its percent completion from the previous page. This results in some weird behavior, described below:

1. User clicks link
2. Progress bar appears and progresses from 0 to ~0.4
3. New page loads
4. Progress bar appears
5. Progress bar progresses from 0 to 1 immediately

This means that there's a strange flash of no progress bar, then a reset progress bar, before finally finishing it.

How can I modify my scripts so that the progress bar completes just before the page redirects?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way I kind of solved it, the progress bar still disappears, because page change is happening and not just a dom swap. But it gives the illusion, something is going on.

I use localstorage[1] to save the progress on unload and pick it up on DOM load, but that's not really necessary you just start the progressbar at 0.3 on DOM loaded if you want. In the best case the site is loading fast enough for the user not to notice any mathematical discrepancies :)

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
    // set starting point
    NProgress.set(0.1);
    // fake the unload progress of a page with an interval
    let timerId = setInterval(() => {
        // increment progress bar
        NProgress.inc();
        // save the progress in local storage to pick up the progress on page load 
        store.set('nprogress', NProgress.status);
    }, 500);
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    // get stored progress
    let start = store.get('nprogress') || 0.2;
    // clean up local storage
    store.remove('nprogress');
    // adjust the value a bit if it got too high
    if(start > 0.7) start = 0.5;
    // start the progress on dom load
    NProgress.set(start);
});

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    NProgress.done();
});
```

[1] https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js#readme